# Memory leak in storyboard under Win8 only?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have made an app, which has a slideshow in it. i run this app on 5 PCs. 3 Win7 and 2 Win8 (all x64, my app is x86). 
On the Win7-PC's I have no problems. 
Under Win8 I get (after a not predictable time) some error messages.
An OutOfMemory-exception and an UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE (HRESULT: 0x88980406).
Microsoft says this about it:

> 6. If System.OutOfMemoryExceptions are being reported, then monitor the process's memory usage in Performance Monitor; particularly the Process\Virtual Bytes, Process\Private Bytes, and .NET CLR Memory# Bytes in All Heaps counters. Also monitor the User Objects and GDI Objects for the process in Windows Task Manager. If you can determine that a specific resource is being exhausted, then troubleshoot the application to fix whatever is causing that resource consumption. Ultimately that should resolve the System.OutOfMemoryException.

I cannot wait 1 to 5 days only monitoring the system and waiting for the error to happen. But maybe someone of you can see the error in my code?

Here is my XAML-Code:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ImgZIndexStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="2"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Image.Opacity" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="3"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FaderStoryboardHide1Show2">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FirstImage" 
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         To="0" Duration="0:00:01" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SecondImage" 
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         To="1" Duration="0:00:01" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Key="FaderStoryboardHide2Show1">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="SecondImage" 
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         To="0" Duration="0:00:01" />
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FirstImage" 
         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
         To="1" Duration="0:00:01" />
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid Name="SlideShowGrid" ZIndex="0">
        <Button Name="SlideShowButton" Click="SlideShowButton_OnClick">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="FirstImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" Style="{StaticResource ImgZIndexStyle}" Opacity="1" />
                <Image x:Name="SecondImage" Stretch="UniformToFill" Style="{StaticResource ImgZIndexStyle}" Opacity="0" />
            </Grid>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And my Class:

```
private void SlideShowTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image newImage;
    Storyboard tempStoryboard;
    if (FirstImage.Opacity == 1)
    {
        tempStoryboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("FaderStoryboardHide1Show2");
        newImage = SecondImage;
    }
    else
    {
        tempStoryboard = (Storyboard)FindResource("FaderStoryboardHide2Show1");
        newImage = FirstImage;
    }
    if (_imageCounter >= _fileList.Count - 1)
        _imageCounter = 0;
    else
        _imageCounter++;
    newImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_fileList[_imageCounter]));
    tempStoryboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: Seems like you need to dispose your previous image `newImage.Source` before assigning a new one

Comment: But I only set a new Source, and dont create a new Image-object. Or have I misunderstood something? Isn't "newImage = SecondImage" not only a reference to the SecondImage?

Comment: `newImage.Source=img1; newImage.Source=img2;` Now you lost the reference to `img1` without releasing its resources....

Comment: I'd suggest using a memory profiler, even if you have to let it run and log for 4 or 5 hours and you don't get the error, it should still show you where the memory leak is.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Yeah, but the error only happens on Win8 and my VS is on a Win7. I dont know how to use a memory profiler without VS.

Comment: If you are developing for multiple platforms, I'd recommend setting up Virtual Machines for every environment you want to support. I have one each for XP through 10, for both X64 and X86 and for both fully updated and for "virgin" installs. Microsoft has trial versions for at least 8 and 10.

Comment: @EZI: First: How should I put a complete Image-object into the Source of another Image-object? And second: I have to create a new BitmapImage to set a completly new picture into the source of an image-object, don't I? I don't want to change from Image1 to Image2, but to set Image2 above Image1 and then change the Source if Image1, so that with the next change the new Image is shown. Would it help to set the Source to null, before assigning a new BitmapImage?

Comment: @MarcelGrüger call `Dispose`

Comment: My 8.1 app had a problem similar to this and I discovered that the image opacity was to blame. I was using image opacity to change the visibility of an image overlaying some video. Once I removed the manually set opacity and used the visibility property instead, the memory leak stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collector uses heuristic algorithms to optimize certain operations. So, you cannot expect consistent behaviour for your memory issues in different PCs.

Don't let your disposable objects to go out of scope without disposing. You should dispose your existing image before you create a new instance.

```
if (newImage != null)
    newImage.Dispose();

newImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_fileList[_imageCounter]));
```

**Edit**

The `Bitmap` class is an implementation of the `Image` class. The Image class is an abstract class. So, use Bitmap which is disposable instead of Image.

```
Bitmap newImage;
....
mewImage.Dispose();
```

Comment: Image has no Dispose-method on default. I dont see how I could use a "using{}" here and to implement it by myself seems to be very complicated. Has someone a simple example for an object like an Image?

Comment: Ok, lets see if I got any wrong thoughts or if you didnt understood me. I have 2 Image-objects with a Source each where a "new BitmapImage" is created every time the method is called. At the end of the method the BitmapImage is put into the Image.Source. The next time I call the method, I would have to Dispose the BitmapImage BEFORE I create a new one. So I should have to Dispose the Source of the Image, that is, to this time, an ImageSource-object. But that cannot be disposed that easily. But to create a new BitmapImage from the ImageSource would not help at all, would it?